# Laravel - querying from existing Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how do i define the table to query from without having to migrate the db ? i've tried manual define in my model but it doesn't helps.

**Eloquent/Model**

```
class Activity extends Model {
     protected $table = 'log_activity';
}
```

my table supposed to be 'log_activity' but not 'activities' as the exception below

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bizoctopus.activities' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `activities` where `activities`.`id` = 6 limit 1)
```

Comment: please tell, which is your table ? log_activity or activities ? And there is no need to migrate table . We can direct create table from phpmyadmin as normal

Comment: table = bizoctopus /
table = log_activity

...kinda new to laravel, not sure how it query from non existing table 'activities' ...

Comment: your question looks incomplete provide more information such as if you are using different connection, whats the database name ..

Comment: Chris wants to know, how to tell laravel/eloquent to use the existing table `log_activity` instead of not existing `activities`. From the error message you can see that his app is trying to query `activities` table.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake creating the model file inside sub directory folder named 'providers' instead of app folder.

thanks for the help.. appreciate it